# PHP, MYSQL как | Обновлять / "Синхронизировать" / Сравнивать | данные в таблице с обновлениями с существующей таблицей

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, синхронизация

Здравствуйте!

имеется таблица на 150К строк с складской номенклатурой

вид таблицы:

Активность | Склад | Ячейка-От | Ячейки-До | Емкость | Владелец | Регион | Timestamp

раз в месяц выходит обновление таблицы и необходимо проводить их синхронизацию

1) деактивировать не найденные строки

2) проверять не изменился ли владелец на совпадающих строках по Склад | Ячейка-От | Ячейки-До

3) добавлять новые строки с данными которых еще не было

искал уже готовые алгоритмы но не нашел, подскажите как это правильно делать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Залить данные в другую временную таблицу с такой же структурой. сделать insert on duplicate key update в основную таблицу из временной. Выполнить `delete from основная_таблица where not exists(select из временной)` или вообще очистить таблицу и заменить на новую версию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE работает же по PRIMARY KEY, а столбцы Склад | Ячейка-От | Ячейки-До не PRIMARY KEY и не Unique

Comment: Но если они не уникальны, как вы собираетесь искать "ту самую" запись, что бы убедится есть она или нет. Если есть некая логика поиска единичной записи - значит по этим полям можно построить уникальный индекс

Comment: Кстати, можно без временной таблицы. добавляете поле "версия" может быть число, может дата. При insert/update ставите сегодняшнюю дату или новое число. После этого все записи старой версии подлежат удалению

Comment: Уникальность задается комбинацией значений, т.е. по комбинации Склад | Ячейка-От | Ячейки-До ничего полезного по поиску "INSERT … ON DUPLICATE UPDATE multi KEY"

Comment: Делаете уникальный индекс `create unique index INDEX_NAME on TABLE(Склад, Ячейка-От, Ячейки-До)` т.е. включаете в индекс все 3 поля.